# QGIS Regex substring for Labelling

Tags: qgis, regular-expression

I'm trying to plot a series of contours in QGIS based on dxf data exported from some specialised mining software.  The attirbute output is pretty ugly and merges a few fields together.

```
DXFName=C$5 DXFGroup= DXFFeature= DXFValue=50.0 DXFDescription=Major contour at level 50.000 DXFPrimitive= DXFLine=0 DXFPattern=0
```

I need to extract just the 'DXFValue=' value to allow categorised symbology, and labelling of the contours.

I've played around with rule based symbology using the 'regexp_substr' function, but I don't have the regex knowledge to produce what I need.

Anyone able to assist?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following expression to extract the values you want:

`regexp_replace("test", '.*DXFValue=([0-9\.\-]{1,}).*', '\\1')`

This function replaces the entire string with the first matched group (the `'\\1'`), which is the string contained in the brackets `'([0-9\.\-]{1,})'`, coming after `'DXFValue='`.

Remember to set the output field type to 'Decimal number (real)'.

[image: field calculator]

Comment: regexp_substr has just been fixed to return the first match group, `regexp_substr('yourstring', 'DXFValue=(\\d*.\\d*)')` should now work.

https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/41f8abb15900f1cdd68888851abeca1602d667d0