# QGIS Regex expression label

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, regular-expression

I'm trying to use regex expression to label my layer in order to show the parcel number.
Here is some examples of what i'm looking for :

```
From this "53042A0027/00M002", to "A27M/2"
From this "53042A2000/02A003", to "A2000A2/3"
From this "53042C0002/00_000", to "A2"
From this "53042G1257/00X000", to "G1257X"
```

EDIT (rules to consider) :

```
Copy the location 6 ==> "53042**G**1257/00X000" 
Then for location 7 to 10, add numbers after the first not null number ==> "53042A**2000**/02A003", "53042A00**27**/00M002"
Then copy location 14 if not equal to "_" ==> "53042A0027/00**M**002"
Then for location 12 and 13, addnumbers after the first not null number ==> "53042A2000/0**2**A003", "53042A0027/00M002"
Then for location 15 to 17, add "/" and all numbers after the first not null number ==> "53042A2000/02A00**3**", "53042A0027/00M00**2**"
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? what isn't working for you?

Comment: how is your question different from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68034/qgis-regex-substring-for-labelling

Comment: Well nothing is working. To be honest, i have no clue how regex expression works even after looking for answers and guides on internet.

Comment: try https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-regular-expressions/modules/intro-to-regex

Comment: From your examples it does not become immediately clear what rules you want to apply: can you state this in words? What characters should be removed, what should be left etc.

Comment: Post edited with the rules to consider :)

Comment: I don't think it will work every time and you need to remove the final slash in some cases, but I think this regexp is a good start : https://regex101.com/r/rhLSUO/1

Comment: Thanks ! When i use it on QGIS though i don't get the same result : regexp_substr( "CaPaKey" ,'[0-9]{5}([A-Z])[0]*([1-9][0-9]*)/([0]|([1-9]))*([_]|([A-Z]))([0]|([1-9])){3}') returns only 'A'

Comment: I thought QGIS was using the python regexp engine, but it is the PCRE engine. I'll fix that and write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function work like expected (at least for the 4 examples) :

```
regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
        "Test", 
        '[0-9]{5}([A-Z])0*([1-9][0-9]*)/(0|([1-9]))*(_|([A-Z]))(0|([1-9])){3}', 
        '\\1\\2\\6\\4/\\8'),
     '/$', 
     ''
)
```

The second 'regexp_replace' function (the one with the big regexp) defines eight groups (the values in brackets) that you can use to generate a new string, like explain by the next figure.

[image: Rexep_replace example]

The first 'regexp_replace' remove the slash `/` character when the new string when it is the last character (I can't do it in the same function).

Comment: It works perfectly fine ! Thank you :) 
If i want to add the symbol "^" before the group \\4 when the number is 1 to 9 how should i proceed ?

Comment: This is usually possible with the conditional statement syntax, like here : https://regex101.com/r/Og9T8H/1 But this syntax does not work in qgis. I don't know if there is an alternative syntax in qgis.